# disable browser localization

Tags: browser, localization

How do I get the websites that I visit to stop localizing the language probably according to my IP location?  This is an website specific issue because, for example economist.com and superuser.com do not do it, but Google Checkout and craigslist.org are doing it.  Is there a way to setup Ubuntu and Firefox so that English will always be used for all web pages displayed?

Edit: Of course many webpages have a link to an English version, but sometimes they don't.  For example I believe such links usually appear on the root resource but sometimes I see non-English languages on child resources where such links do not appear.  Example: most Blogger.com blogs appear in English but when I go to the blogger's profile ("view my complete profile"), it appears in another language that matches my geographic location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the website is using geolocation by IP address, there is nothing you can do – short of setting up a proxy server somewhere in UK or USA.

If the site is using `Accept-Language`, [meinertz's answer](/questions/258677) applies.

Answer (score 0):

There are some settings in Firefox you can try to mess with. I'm using Firefox 4 on Windows, but i think you should be able to find it in approximately the same place:

Open the options (if you are using ff3 on linux i think it's under Edit -> Preferences...) and switch to the "Content"-tab. There should be some language specific options which you can try to mess with.

Comment: Thanks but File/Preferences/Content/Languages is already set to English.

Answer (score 0):

in opera chromium based it was under `Settings -> Languages` I remove the additional language so sites will see one proffering .